# cannot import LanguageTranslatorV3 in AWS EC2

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am now trying to use the IBM Natural Language Translator in AWS EC2. However, I find I cannot import the LanguageTranslatorV3 in the AWS EC2, which can be done on my laptop. The error is shown below. Is there anyone that can help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

```
from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-0d0e9b329a15> in <module>()
----> 1 from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3

ImportError: cannot import name 'LanguageTranslatorV3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a dependency on `watson-developer-cloud` in your applications `requirements.txt` file.